# Multinomial theorem for rational exponent in application to a trinomial

Tags: power-series, binomial-theorem, hypergeometric-function, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

sHello to everyone.What I am trying (and I can not find) is an expression in series the following trio with rational exponent:
$$(1+x+y)^n$$ 
where n is a rational number, $$\mid x\mid<1,\mid y\mid<1$$

As it is known from the binomial theorem:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^k=_2F_1(-n,1,1,x)$$
What I'm looking for is a similar expression for the trinomial illustrated above.
Remembering some notion on multinomial theorem i proceeds this:
$$(1+x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{s=0}^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{s} x^{k-s}  y^{s}$$ 
Do you think this result is correct?If it were correct, how can I rewrite it in the form of hypergeometric function of several variables as shown before for the binomial theorem?
Thanks very much for your help and for your time.

Comment: Have you looked at the "Multinomial Theorem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Yes, but there is not what I am looking for unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With me always check!
Of course, you could just write :)

$_{2}F_{1}\left(-n,1;1;\left(x+y\right)\right)$
or 
$_{1}F_{0}\left(-n;-;\left(x+y\right)\right)$

But there is a named two variable form in $x^{n}y^{s}$

To facilitate the conversion we rephrase in terms of rising Pochhammer functions; the ones used in hypergeometric function definition:
$\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\
k
\end{array}\right)$ $=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{k!}  $

$\left(1+z\right)^{\alpha}={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{k!}z^{k}$

$\left(1+\left(x+y\right)\right)^{\alpha}={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{k!}\left(x+y\right)^{k}$
$I=\left(1+\left(x+y\right)\right)^{\alpha}={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{k!}\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^{k}\left(x\right)^{k}
 $
$={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{k!}\left(x\right)^{k}{\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{k}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
s
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{s}
 $
 $={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{1}\left(x\right)^{k}{\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{k}}\frac{1}{s!\left(k-s\right)!}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{s}
 $
$={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{k}}\frac{1}{s!\left(k-s\right)!}\left(x^{k-s}\right)\left(y\right)^{s}
 $
We reformat it to
Bateman's Special functions 5.7.1 http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf
or
Wolfram's Horn's list http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornFunction.html
$I={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}{\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{k}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(-\alpha\right)_{k}}{(k-s)!s!}\left(x\right)^{k-s}\left(y\right)^{s}$
Let $n=k-s$
$={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}{\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{k}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+s}\left(-\alpha\right)_{\left(n+s\right)}}{(n)!s!}\left(x\right)^{n}\left(y\right)^{s}$
$={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}{\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{k}}\frac{\left(-\alpha\right)_{\left(n+s\right)}}{(n)!s!}\left(-x\right)^{n}\left(-y\right)^{s}$
$I=F_{2}\left(\alpha,1,1,1,1,-x,-y\right)
 $

Comment: I do not really know how to thank you, congratulations! I did not know about the Horn's function,i will remedy it immediately and study it .... thanks again!

Comment: While reading “Generalized Hypergeometric Functions” by Slater I found in Chapter 8 on Appell series.  
For Instance:  
If b=c  

 $F_{2}\left(\alpha;b,b';b,c';x,y\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{\alpha}}\,_{2}F_{1}\left(\alpha,b;c';\frac{y}{\left(1-x\right)}\right)$  

Or in our case: $b=c=1,b'=c'=1$  

$\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{^{\alpha}}}\,_{1}F_{0}\left(\alpha;-;\frac{y}{\left(1-x\right)}\right)$  

 While not profound, or difficult, shows that the symmetries inside of the combinatorial problem are recast into symmetries of coefficients.

Comment: Sorry about the trashiness of the last comment.   I can't seem to get presentations I like in under the 5-minute rule here.  
 Mentally add a bunch of cr/lf 's :)  In any case Chapter 8 is dedicated to Appell series and intelligible with a little (?) thought.

Comment: I thank you very much for your interest, I will go straight to the issue more deeply since hypergeometric functions are a topic that fascinates me very much and is also very useful for the research I am doing. You never end up learning!